# View GPS Data from SQL Server database in map

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, google-maps, gps

Hello I have MS SQL Server database with a table Drives with columns Latitude and Longitude. Is there a simple way how to see these GPS Points in the map using SQL Server Management Studio or some similar tool. Plugin for ssms for example.. ?

Comment: Hi Jan P and welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately it seems to me like your question is off-topic for two reasons A. It's too broad and B. It's primarily opinion based. See this page http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and this one http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking for more info about what Stack Overflow is looking for in good questions.

Comment: This article: [Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3) should give you the basic concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Database Studio](http://http:%5C%5Csqldatabasestudio.com) has built in functionality of showing GPS data on the google maps. The free version provides only open street maps, paid also google maps.

Displaying map is a little bit tricky, your columns have to be name **Latitude** and **Longitude**. If your columns are called lat and lng, create simple select like

```
SELECT *
,lat as Latitude
,lng as Longitude
FROM outcodepostcodes
```

press F5 and you should be able to see data and map in another tab. I'm adding screenshot. Also when you select data you should see map in cell detail.
[image]